# Text message queues maximum length?

Tags: mobile

I'd like to make an app to send/receive text messages using a GSM modem. However, I've seen that a modem can only receive/send about 8-10 text messages per minute. So if I receive 200 incoming text messages within a 10 minute span (like I'm at a conference and I ask people to sign up), do they get queued up on the modem? Do I have to deal with in in my application? Are they queued up by AT&T (or some other wireless carrier)? Is there a maximum length to the queue? Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to worry about it.

You can setup the modem to store the messages internally as opposed to on the SIM by setting the preferred storage location to "ME" which will give you whatever memory resources are built into the modem - way larger than whats available on the SIM.

If that fills up, when next the device receives a message it can't handle it will report that fact back to the SMSMC which will record the failure and add the message to a retry queue.

There is no standard for the retry policy, so they may retry a few minutes later, gradually increasing the interval as failures build up upto a total retry time equaling the "validity period" setup on the senders handset, or their own upper limit.

Comment: awesome! While I have your attention, do you have any modem recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: I tend to just buy cheap ones from ebay

Comment: And then just buy a SIM to place inside? An only texting plan or something like that?

Comment: Either that, or just a Pay-As-You-Go plan